# How to use Debug with/without Microsoft Application Verifier in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, application-verifier

So I've installed the application verifier to help me with debugging, however I don't know how to use it properly.

First off, it seems to have attached itself permanently to visual studio. Whenever I run any application in debugging mode through visual studio, the verifier automatically steps in. This is a problem, because it slows down the execution massively, but there doesn't seem to be a way to run the debugger without the verifier anymore? I really don't want to reinstall it every time I want to use it, and then deinstall it again.

Secondly, it does seem to find leaks and such efficiently, but I'm not sure what to do with the output messages:

```
=======================================
VERIFIER STOP 00000900: pid 0x43C: A heap allocation was leaked. 

    12626FE8 : Address of the leaked allocation. Run !heap -p -a <address> to get additional information about the allocation.
    04E2BA6C : Address to the allocation stack trace. Run dps <address> to view the allocation stack.
    11E0AFE0 : Address of the owner dll name. Run du <address> to read the dll name.
    6C660000 : Base of the owner dll. Run .reload <dll_name> = <address> to reload the owner dll. Use 'lm' to get more information about the loaded and unloaded modules.


=======================================
```

Where can I run the listed commands? There's no separate console, and starting the verifier directly starts up a GUI, but you can't enter any commands there either.

I'm using windows 8.1 with visual studio ultimate 2013. The project is a C++ project.

// EDIT:

Regarding the first issue: I just had to remove the executable from the list in the GUI, I didn't think that would have any effects if the program wasn't running.

Comment: May I ask how did you attach Application Verifier in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run these commands in WinDBG which you can get [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)

You can also run these commands in Immediate Window of Visual Studio when debugging using debugger from WDK (which is essentially WinDBG).

Comment: Installing WinDBG with Windows SDK 10.0.10586.15 or installing WDK 10.0.10586.0 do both not make WinDBG available in VS2013. So there must be additionals steps to do.

Answer (score 1):

Answering side question how to attach App Verifier in Visual Studio:

1. Run Application Verifier GUI
2. Select binary you want to debug (exe/dll)
3. Select options to check
4. Click [Save] - it's automatically tracked until you explicitly remove the application. These settings survive even system restart.