# WinDbg commands not working in VS Immediate window

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, application-verifier

I've installed AppVerifier and have it's extended error reporting appearing in the Output-Debug window:

```
VERIFIER STOP 00000202: pid 0x1714: Freeing heap block containing an active critical section. 

10177F2C : Critical section address. Run !cs -s <address> to get more information.
044885D4 : Critical section initialization stack trace. Run dps <address> to dump the stack trace.
10177ED0 : Heap block address.
00000130 : Heap block size.
```

But when I try to use the suggested WinDbg commands in the [immediate window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27215035/85661) I end up with errors.

```
!cs -s 10177F2C
CXX0013: Error: missing operator
!cs -s <10177F2C>
CXX0017: Error: symbol "s <10177F2C>" not found
dps 044885D4
CXX0004: Error: syntax error
dps <044885D4>
CXX0017: Error: symbol "dps <044885D4>" not found
```

Do I need to do additional installation/configuration beyond just installing AppVerifier to make use of this functionality?

Comment: VisualStudio 2015 has a new command set for its debugger, which differs significantly from WinDbg.

Comment: @JA I'm using 2010 at the moment, does it also use the new command set?  If so, where can I find instructions on how to map its commands to/from WinDbg commands?